# Discrete SeekBar Slider with AppCompat

Tags: android, slider, android-seekbar

I found [this](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) library to use `Discrete Slider/Seekbar` in my app, but what if i don't want to use any external lib, i am using **AppCompat** Lib - 23.0.0

So my question is how may use Discrete Slider [Numeric/Range Picker/Seekbar] (using AppCompat Lib)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614714/discrete-seekbar-in-android-app It might be useful