# Android Seekbar: how to limit the range that can be set by user?

Tags: android

I have a discrete SeekBar that can take a value from 0 to 10. But I want to let the user select values from 1 to 9 only. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discrete seekbar in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614714/discrete-seekbar-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I've implemented custom `OnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
binding.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                when(progressValue) {
                    0 -> seekBar.progress = 1
                    10 -> seekBar.progress = 9
                }
            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically set max limit of seekbar after the user has given desired range like this:

```
seekbar.setMax(userInput);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't resovle my question, because `max` property sets maximum value of `SeekBar`. In my case, it's 10, but I want to prevent users from setting this value, but let that value visible.